# Change permission of a ZipEntry

Tags: java, zip

I'm trying to generate a zip file with `java.util.zip` API and I haven't found any way to set permissions of a [ZipEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html). An idea?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible using `java.util.zip`.  Try Apache [commons-compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/).  Specifically, you want to call [setMode](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/AsiExtraField.html#setMode%28int%29) on an [AsiExtraField](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/AsiExtraField.html), and then add that to a [ZipArchiveEntry](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveEntry.html) that you put in a [ZipArchiveOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveOutputStream.html).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't do that using [ZipEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html) apis. Though you use the [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) apis `setWritable(), setReadable()` and `setExecutable()` etc. to change permissions on the file.