# Java/Groovy: ZIP files and assign permissions to them

Tags: java, groovy, archive, zip

I am developing groovy-based helper for Maven Assembly plugin and I am stuck with permission management. I am creating assembly on Windows machine, which means that native unix-style permission management is not available.

Is it possible to zip some files using Groovy/Java, while specifying permissions to be assigned to files inside archive?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699334/change-permission-of-a-zipentry

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for that:

```
.setUnixMode(int unixMode)
```

Complete working sample for future generations:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveException;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveStreamFactory;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils;

public class Archiver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ArchiveException, IOException {
        /* Create Output Stream that will have final zip files */
        OutputStream zip_output = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                "zip_output.zip"));

        /*
         * Create Archive Output Stream that attaches File Output Stream / and
         * specifies type of compression
         */
        ArchiveOutputStream logical_zip = new ArchiveStreamFactory()
                .createArchiveOutputStream(ArchiveStreamFactory.ZIP, zip_output);

        /* Create Archieve entry - write header information */
        ZipArchiveEntry e1 = new ZipArchiveEntry("z1/labrat-1.txt");
        e1.setUnixMode(0777);
        logical_zip.putArchiveEntry(e1);
        /* Copy input file */
        IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(new File("labrat-1.txt")), logical_zip);
        /* Close Archieve entry, write trailer information */
        logical_zip.closeArchiveEntry();
        /* Repeat steps for file - 2 */
        ZipArchiveEntry e2 = new ZipArchiveEntry("z2/labrat-2.txt");
        e2.setUnixMode(0777);
        logical_zip.putArchiveEntry(e2);
        IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(new File("labrat-2.txt")), logical_zip);
        logical_zip.closeArchiveEntry();

        /* Finish addition of entries to the file */
        logical_zip.finish();
        /* Close output stream, our files are zipped */
        zip_output.close();
    }
}
```